# When using C# code in powershell, what is the difference between CSharp and CSharpVersion3?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a class that calls `System.Enum.TryParse()`. When I call the `Add-Type` and use `-Language CSharpVersion3`, I get a

> 'System.Enum' does not contain a definition for 'TryParse'

error but no such error when using `-Language CSharp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 3.0 of C# targets version 3.5 of the .NET Runtime<sup>[1]</sup>.

[`Enum.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd783499(v=vs.100).aspx) was introduced in version 4.0

---

[<sup>[1]:</sup> Wikipedia has a nice language-to-framework version matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions)

Comment: Jessen - How do I target versions 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: @pauzinho By specifying `CSharp` - it'll default to the newest supported by current runtime

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I wish information like that was mentioned in the documentation.  It provides the valid options but not the *why* or *what*